# ApexChart not displaying properly in cloumns container

Tags: javascript, css, apexcharts

I'm trying to render my ApexChart in a container with this CSS property: `columns: 2;`
When I remove that property, it gets renders as assumed:

[image: Correct render]

But with the giving CSS this happens:

[image: broken render]

I have no idea why this is happening...
As I already tried a lot, I'm very sure, that the given line of CSS is the source of the error and not anything else.

I created a fiddle which recreates the bug: https://jsfiddle.net/levi_hrb/9dzrxv73/12/

I know that it would be possible to order the containers with JavaScript into two masonry columns. The problem is, that the content and height is often changing, so it would be the best if there were a pure CSS solution.

I would be very happy for any help, thank you very much!

Comment: Can you provide code to duplicate the problem. It's much easier for someone to help you that way

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I added a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/levi_hrb/9dzrxv73/12/

Comment: I got literaly no idea why this is working but when I add this CSS 
`.widget-box {
     display: table; // this must be table not block
}`
then it suddenly works, for idk what reason… Crazy workaround but fine for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above design is working well with `grid`.

```css
.widget-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);

  .widget-box {
    display: block;
    break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    padding: 4px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div class="col-12 widget-container">

  <div class="widget-box">
    <div class="apexchart" id="apexchart" style="min-height: 315px;"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="widget-box">
    <div class="apexchart" id="apexchart2" style="min-height: 315px;"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this code is, that I have more than 2 containers, but I want to split them in only 2 columns. If I use your code with e.g., 3 containers, then there are also 3 columns. Is there any way I can set the columns fixed to 2 (also not 1...)?
Thanks!

Comment: @levi.hrb Hey, for fixing the columns to 2, you can use grid with `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)`.

Comment: thanks, that helps already a lot, there is just one more problem .
In the grid all cells are of the same height, which means if there is a small container on the left and a tall one on the right, then the third container (the second on the left side) will have a big gap on top. Is there any way I can get a masonry look?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @levi.hrb yup, you could achive this thing, refer this blog [link](https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/). I hope it would help you out.